# Mount google bucket during startup

Tags: linux, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm trying to mount google bucket to an instance during startup (or access)
1st way - via fstab:

```
alex-backup-test /mount gcsfuse uid=0,gid=0,rw,user,key_file=/etc/google/service-account.json
```

After reboot it isn't mounted (
But when I'm trying to do this manually - it's ok

```
mount /mount/
Calling gcsfuse with arguments: --gid 0 --key-file /etc/google/service-account.json -o rw -o noexec -o nosuid -o nodev --uid 0 alex-backup-test /mount
Using mount point: /mount
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
```

2nd way - to use autofs:
In auto.master:

```
/mount /etc/auto.gcsfuse        --timeout=60 --verbose
```

auto.gcsfuse:

bucket  -fstype=gcsfuse,uid=0,gid=0,rw,noexec,nodev,key_file=/etc/google/service-account.json :alex-backup-test

In the log:

```
May 10 09:25:09 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: mounted indirect on /mount with timeout 60, freq 15 seconds
May 10 09:25:21 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: attempting to mount entry /mount/bucket
May 10 09:25:21 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: >> Calling gcsfuse with arguments: -o rw -o noexec -o nodev --uid 0 --gid 0 --key-file /etc/google/service-account.json alex-backup-test /mount/bucket
May 10 09:25:21 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: >> Using mount point: /mount/bucket
May 10 09:25:21 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: >> Opening GCS connection...
May 10 09:25:21 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: >> Opening bucket...
May 10 09:25:22 alex-backup-test automount[31312]: >> Mounting file system...
```

And it's stuck.

ps. but options for gcsfuse seems similar on manual and autofs mount.

Many thanks in advice !

Answer (score 0):

NVM, problem was caused by SELinux ...